# How to Give List of Objects IDs and add a click event based on each List IDs in Django

Tags: javascript, django

Here in my Django code, I have a list of prices. Now I gave them unique IDs which works well, but when I try to add a click event, the click event only works for only one list item continuously.

```
      {% for price in logistic_branch_pricing %}
      <h1 id="select-delivery-location-{{price.id}}" 
   onclick="calculateDeliveryPrice()">{{ price.id }}-{{price.small_kg_price}}
      </h1>
      
      {% endfor %}

   {% for price in logistic_branch_pricing %}
   <script>
    function calculateDeliveryPrice() {
      var omo = document.getElementById("select-delivery-location-{{ price.id }}")
      omo.classList.add('d-none')
      console.log(omo)
    }
  </script>
   {% endfor %}
```

Comment: what you're trying to do? Are you trying to access id of each prices?

Comment: Yes, I want to access the IDs of each prices and once the individual price ID is clicked, I want that particular price to now have a new class of "d-none".

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to add loop over your **`<script>`** tag just pass event keyword inside your javascript onclick function like this

```
{% for price in logistic_branch_pricing %}
   <h1 id="select-delivery-location-{{price.id}}" onclick="calculateDeliveryPrice(event)">{{ price.id }}-{{price.small_kg_price}}
   </h1>
{% endfor %}
```

and inside your javascript do like this

```
<script>
  function calculateDeliveryPrice(e) {
      var omo = e.target
      omo.classList.add('d-none')
      var small_kg_price = omo.textContent.split('-')[1] // return small_kg_price
      console.log(omo) // returns element
      console.log(omo.id) // returns id of element
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I am trying to get this, "small_kg_price" but I am unable to get this cos it says undefined. I tried with omo.id which works well, but omo.small_kg_price doesn't work.

Comment: Hello @Arthur check I've updated my answer now you can get **small_kg_price**.